# How to show Admob interstitial in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

My app cant show interstitial. If i run the app with the test device id than it shows me the interstitial test window from google. But without the test device id it shows me nothing. I make the same steps like intergrate the smart_banner. My app shows the smart_banner but not the interstitial. It is possible that i work with the wrong class... there exist also a interstitial class but i use the AdView class. I have no idea did anyone know a good tutorial for including interstitial in libgdx ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {

private AdView adView;
private AdView fullAdView;
private RelativeLayout layout;
private final String ADCODE = "XXX";
private final String FULLADCODE = "XXX";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    // Create the layout
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // AdMob View 
    fullAdView = new AdView(this);
    fullAdView.setAdUnitId(FULLADCODE);
    fullAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE);

    View gameView = initializeForView(new FPGame(new RequestHandler(adView, fullAdView)), cfg);
    ...
    AdRequest fadRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    fullAdView.loadAd(fadRequest);

    fullAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    layout.requestLayout();
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `InterstitialAd` instead `AdView`  class
Follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/interstitial/src/com/google/example/gms/ads/advanced/InterstitialSample.java)

Comment: If i use the wrong class for interstitial its okay. But why my full banner dont appear at the screen ? Only if i try it on my test device there appear the google ad window that it was successful.